# Scraping followers from Twitter using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

I'm new to Python, and have been trying to code an app that can scrape data from Twitter. I tried searching all similar possible solutions on stack, and internet but failed.

I want to scrape all these usernames:
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKEj2.png)

This is my code:

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/twitterusername/followers")
sleep(10)

usernames = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("css-901oao.css-16my406.r-poiln3.rbcqeeo.r-qvutc0")
for username in usernames:
    print(username.get_attribute("href"))
```

The result I get:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

... *continued*

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why the huge `sleep(10)`?

Comment: I'm just testing that. I will change that later. Can you please help me? :(

Comment: it's not a good practice to use this kind of class because they're obfuscated and will change.simply use the parrent and reach the children below. `document.querySelectorAll('div[aria-label="Timeline: Followers"] a[role="link"]').forEach(a => console.log(a['href']))`

Comment: I do not understand this... could you probably provide me the fix using my code?

Comment: I'm using Python. I think the above code is in Java/JavaScript.

Comment: sure, no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so, using BeautifulSoup is off the table.
we can use only selenium to handle this.

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
    url = a.get_property('href')
    if 'search' in url:
        return 
    print(url.replace("https://twitter.com/", "@")
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I was intending to do this in Selenium. :(

Comment: what's the problem with using a parser like BeautifulSoup?  you can't install an extra light package?

Comment: I'm using Selenium and most of my functions are done in that... :( I'm sorry I didn't mean to come off as differently. I really appreciate your time and effort... it's just I preferred Selenium.

Comment: No worries, I updated my answer and used only selenium :)

Comment: It works. There's one issue... it also shows other links. 

Like this:

https://twitter.com/search?q=%23Whexcosystem&src=hashtag_click

Comment: well not in my case, it only prints the followers.

Comment: you can filter the links and don't show them if there's something like a search in it.

Comment: Yeah, those links are still there when I added new code but replaced with "@". How can we filter them in the code?

Comment: if all other links have search in them simply check for search in the href. 
if not 'search' in url:
    print(url.replace("https://twitter.com/", "@"))

Comment: I'm confused lol. I'm too new to implement this. Can you update your code please? And thank you so much! This will work for now.

Comment: ok, I updated my code. please consider accepting this answer since it works properly